# How would I click on a link (a tag) and open a PDF stored un public/pdf folder in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, next.js

I am using next to create a site, I have folder public/pdf/example.pdf and want to open this in a new window when user clicks on the link (a tag). Which looks like this:

```
<a href="/pdf/nameofpdf.pdf" target="_blank">click</a>
```

However, in the new window I get failed to load PDF document.

How would I go about opening a pdf using Nextjs?

Comment: What is HTTP code of the PDF? (using the dev tools)

Comment: seems it doesn't recognise a PDF file in public folder, in sources (dev tools) it doesn't show the file.

Comment: I just am not sure how to load it

Comment: I can't replicate the error you're seeing? https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-driscoll-93vel?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: your pdf link opening is blocked?

Comment: https://93vel.sse.codesandbox.io/pdf/example.pdf should either try to open the file, or download it, depending on the browser. Make sure to allow "popups" for https://93vel.sse.codesandbox.io

Comment: seems if I replace it with your PDF it works, perhaps my PDF isn't correctly formatted. Even though I can open it in the browser.

Comment: Yep, seems I put it through a PDF converter (even though it is an PDF) and used that, it now works correctly. Thanks for your help, without your PDF quick sandbox it would've taken me a lot longer to realise it wasn't a nextjs issue. Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad I could help